# Afraid of nail cutting

Tags: grammar

Can you give the right context for each below?

1. I am afraid of nail cutting.
2. I am afraid of nail trim.
3. I am afraid of nail trims.

Comment: Can you give us an explanation of what you think is correct? If we don't know what you know, we can't help you much.

Comment: I would use the first one, but have no idea what the others mean and how they differ from the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Nail cutting usually refers to the cutting (or possibly clipping) of fingernails or toenails, possibly with [nail-clippers](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=nail-clippers&hl=en&biw=1024&bih=699&site=webhp&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=gzhgVZm9CYW58gX9rYH4BA&ved=0CCkQsAQ) but more likely with [nail-scissors](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=nail-clippers&hl=en&biw=1024&bih=699&site=webhp&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=gzhgVZm9CYW58gX9rYH4BA&ved=0CCkQsAQ#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=nail-scissors) (as nail clipping would be the preferred description in the former case). Summary: this refers to a **verb**.
2. Nail trimming would be an alternative phrase for either nail cutting or nail clipping as in 1., and **I am afraid of *a* nail trim** would be equivalent to **I am afraid of nail trimming** and therefore roughly the same as 1. However there is no article (*a* or *the*) present in the example and either the grammar of the sentence is incorrect, or it refers not to the act, but a **collective noun**. A possible collective noun could be associated with [building nails](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=building%20nail%20trim&hl=en&biw=1024&bih=699&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=uTtgVYEYi5nxBbm6g5AE&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=building%20nails), but is more likely to be [nail-clippings](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=building%20nail%20trim&hl=en&biw=1024&bih=699&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=uTtgVYEYi5nxBbm6g5AE&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=nail%20clippings). Summary: this refers to a **collective noun**.
3. This example is slightly ambiguous at a stretch it could refer to the regular plural form of individual members of the collective noun in 2., but it is more likely to refer to a plurality of the acts in 1. as English parsimoniously prefers to use collective nouns (and not pluralize them if it can help it) if they are applicable rather than plurals. Summary: this refers to a **plural (action) noun** (acts of the verb in 1).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, do you mean they equally mean the same and can be used interchangably, if I change nail trim to a nail trim?

Comment: @JoeKim yes that change to number 2. would make it semantically equivalent to the others

Answer (score 1):

> I am afraid of nail cutting.
>   I am afraid of nail trim.
>   I am afraid of nail trims.

Afraid of {something}. *Something* must be a noun, or like a noun.

*cutting* is like a noun.

*nail trims* is a plural noun modified by the noun "nail" used adjectivally.

However, *trim* is a verb (bare infinitive) unless you use an article: "*a* nail trim".

Comment: Thank you, TRomano. And can I ask you the same question I added for Bruised Reed?

Comment: #1 and #3 are grammatical, but none of them is idiomatic. A native speaker would say: "I'm afraid of getting my nails trimmed" or if considering a job at a nail salon: "I'm afraid of trimming people's nails."

Comment: Thank you. Since you suggested getting "my" nails trimmed, I need to ask more. It is my son who is afraid of getting his nails done and also seeing or hearing others doing theirs done. It is not only about himself but nail trimming itself is a sacry thing for him. In this case what setence would make more sense, or does the one above sound correct?

Comment: Your son could say "Nail trimming scares me." Or "I'm afraid of nail trimming".